How I can USB passthrough wifi card into android emulator as I do upon on other hypervisors
I managed to run an android emulator:
$ emulator Android30
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-pcmagas/emu-crash-34.2.14.db, detection is enabled for process: 93905
INFO    | Android emulator version 34.2.14.0 (build_id 11834374) (CL:N/A)
ERROR   | No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'
$ emulator -avd Android30

And I have a realtek Realtek RTL8188EUS wi-fi usb dongle. How I can passthrough it to the emulator so I can make the emulator manage it directly?
I want to do similarly as I do upon Virtualbox:


As already mentioned in comments to your other question you're wasting your time trying to make that device work with Android. It doesn't work OOTB in any modern desktop Linux yet let alone in Android where you would need to seriously compile the drivers and hope for the best.
